# JSF 2 / primefaces/ jquery : autoselect, autotab and highlight feature for input elements?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

Just want to ask around before implementing own's solution using javascript and css. 
I wonder if in core jsf tags / primefaces / jquery have the following features :

1. auto-select : When receiving focus, an input text would auto-select all of the texts, so that it could be replaced instantly by user input without having the user to delete the whole unselected/unblocked string.
2. autotab : Would like to tab to the next input based on the tabindex defined when the value inputted has reached the limit of defined maxlength in the input text.
3. highlight : Would like to have a different border or background when an element is focused

Thank you !

Regards,
Albert Kam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first point this might works for you...

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
// Select field contents
this.select();
```

});

For second point this discussion might help you....
[Auto Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474633/jquery-tabindex-fix)

For third point...

```
 $("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("color","red");});
```